# Meaning of 「にならない」

Tags: grammar

What does *ni naranai* mean below?

> [提出]{ていしゅつ}に[遅]{おく}れた[場合]{ばあい}は[減点]{げんてん}**にならない**
>   teishutsu ni okureta baai ha genten ni naranai

"Points will not be deducted if there is delay in submission" - is that correct?

Comment: Can you please add what you think "ni naranai" might be and how do you understand that sentence as a whole?

Comment: Points will not be dedcted if there is delay in submission - is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Is your translation correct?

Yes, your translation "Points will not be deducted if there is a delay in submission" is a correct one.

### 「〜にならない」とは？

For a more literal translation to address your question about the meaning of にならない

- 提出に遅れた場合は

> In the event (case) of a late submission

- （結果が）減点にならない

> (the outcome) will not be a point deduction.

### Explanation

I imagine some confusion might stem from the question, 何が何にならない？. In your example, 何が減点にならない？ In many cases where this isn't explicit, the 何 in 何が can be thought of as "reality", "result", "outcome", etc., and this is understood　-- "(the result) will not be a point deduction".